# Creating multiple records in ruby from a hash of arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I have a response consisting of a hash of arrays within a hash.  I need to create three records (see below) in ruby/rails.

```
{
    "first_name" => [John, Tom, Michael],
    "last_name" => [Smith, Watts, Pit],
    "email" => [John.smith@gmail.com, tom.watts@gmail.com,  mike.pit@gmail.com]
}

id  || first_name   || last_name  || email
----------------------------------------------
1   || John         ||  Smith     || john.smith@gmail.com
2   || Tom          ||  Watts     || tom.watts@gmail.com
3   || Michael      ||  Pit       || mike.pit@gmail.com
```

I'm having difficulties understanding how to approach this. Any help would be very appreciated.

So far I have:

```
response.keys.each do |field_name|
  response[field_name].each do |value|
     puts "#{field_name} => #{value}"
     User.create!(
       first_name: value['first_name'],
       last_name: value['last_name'],
       email:  value['email']
     )
  end
end
```

Comment: `hash of arrays within a hash` is a bit confusing. Is it always as in your example?

Comment: Yes, it always is.

Answer (score 0):

How about an approach like -

```
def create_records_from_responses!(responses)
  items = responses.values.first.length
  fields = responses.keys
  users = []

  # Don't process an empty set
  return if items.zero?

  # Wrap creation of User objects in a transaction
  # If one fails, it rolls back all created records
  # As per transaction documentation, you still have to manually
  # handle the propagated error
  # See: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html
  # In this case we named the method with a `!` to indicate that it might raise
  # an error. Whatever is calling this should rescue and handle the error

  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    (0..items).each do |i|
      attributes = {}
      fields.each { |field| attributes[field] = responses[field][i] }

      users << User.create!(attributes)
    end
  end

  users
```

This makes 2 assumptions -

1. Your `responses` hash is correctly formed. If there are mismatched arrays for each key then things could go wrong. You should validate its form beforehand
2. The number of users you're creating isn't huge. As you can see it rebuilds the `attributes` in each loop. It's not a huge deal if it's 10-20 records but consider optimizing that if you're handling more.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are guaranteed the length of the arrays is the same, and the order does not change, you can do something like:

```
data = {
  first_name: ["John", "Tom", "Michael"],
  last_name: ["Smith", "Watts","Pit"],
  email: ["John.smith@gmail.com", "tom.watts@gmail.com",  "mike.pit@gmail.com"]
}

0.upto(data[:first_name].length-1) do |i|
  record = {
    first_name: data[:first_name][i],
    last_name: data[:last_name][i],
    email: data[:email][i]
  }
  User.create!(record)
end
```

You can also get crazy with .zip and .each_slice, though I think the above is more straightforward and clear.

```
maxlen = data[:first_name].length
first_name_fields = Array.new(maxlen, 'first_name')
last_name_fields = Array.new(maxlen, 'last_name')
email_fields = Array.new(maxlen, 'email')
records = first_name_fields.zip(data[:first_name], last_name_fields, data[:last_name], email_fields, data[:email])
records.map!{|x| x.each_slice(2).to_a.to_h}
records.each{|record| User.create!(record)}
```

Answer (score 0):

As simple as this:

```
response.values.transpose.each { |record|
  User.create!(data.keys.zip(record).to_h)
}
```

`response.values` will give us an array of arrays (array of field values for each field), and `transpose` will flip it around so we have array of records. Then for each record, just add field names, hashify and pass to `#create!`.

Comment: I like the simplicity of this answer. Unfortunately some of my field names don't directly match to the hash keys, so I need to manually associate them.